# Remove added pushpin Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I've just created a new project using Bing map control (as default in toolbox).
And I use following method to create a new pushpin

```
void DrawMyLocationOverLay()
{
    MapLayer layer1 = new MapLayer(); 
    Pushpin pushpin1 = new Pushpin();
    pushpin1.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
    pushpin1.Tag = "myLocation";
    pushpin1.Content = "My car"; 
    MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay(); 
    overlay1.Content = pushpin1;
    overlay1.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate; 
    layer1.Add(overlay1); 
    MyMap.Layers.Add(layer1);

}
```

**Ofcourse, it' works.**

And now, I'm using following methods to update pushpin if location changed

```
 private void GetCoordinate()
 {
     var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
     {
         MovementThreshold = 2
     };

     watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
     watcher.Start();
 }

 private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
 {
     myGeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, 
                                         e.Position.Location.Longitude);

     DrawMyLocationOverLay();
     // Problem here

 }
```

This will create a new pushpin and not remove pushpin created earlier( pushpin created in first method)

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating an entirely new `MapLayer`, `Pushpin` and `MapOverlay` every time you call your `DrawMyLocationOverLay` function. Don't you really just want to move just the `Pushpin` (or maybe just the `MapOverlay`, I can't quite tell)?

In that case when you create them, you'd store them in a member variable. Then in your `watcher_PositionChanged` handler, you'd update them (rather than creating new ones).

Something like:

```
private MapLayer _MapLayer;
private Pushpin _Pushpin;
private MapOverlay _MapOverlay;

void InitialDraw()
{
    MapLayer _MapLayer = new MapLayer(); 
    Pushpin _Pushpin = new Pushpin();
    _Pushpin.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
    _Pushpin.Tag = "myLocation";
    _Pushpin.Content = "My car"; 
    MapOverlay _MapOverlay = new MapOverlay(); 
    _MapOverlay.Content = _Pushpin;
    _MapOverlay.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate; 
    _MapLayer.Add(_MapOverlay); 
    MyMap.Layers.Add(_MapLayer);
}

void DrawMyLocationOverLay()
{
    _Pushpin.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
    _MapOverlay.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
}
```

Comment: can you build code base on my code ?

I just want to update my Pushpin when location of created pushpin changed

Comment: My edit should get you started. StackOverflow isn't a site to have someone write code for you. But that should send you off in the right direction.